# decode stored json result string in shared preferences

Tags: json, flutter, dart, mobile, dio

When the app launch it triggers an API call and in my case, I want to store the response data for later use, so I used shared preferences for that and stored response data as a string. now I want to properly decode the data to use, from the stored string from shared preferences.

here is how I covert the data to string,

```js
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

Response response = await _dio.post(
        _baseUrl,
        data: {"index": indexNum, "password": password},
        options: Options(contentType: Headers.formUrlEncodedContentType),
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var result = response.data;
        
        //convert result data to string
        var resultData = Result.encode(result);
        
        // store the resultData in shared_preferences
        prefs.setString('results', resultData);
        
      }
```

encode method,

```js
class Result {
  Result({
    required this.table,
    required this.data,
  });

  String table;
  List<Data> data;

  factory Result.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Result(
        table: json["table"],
        data: List<Data>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Data.fromJson(x))),
      );

  //encode method
  static String encode(List<dynamic> results) => json.encode(
        results.map((result) => result.toString()).toList(),
      );
      
}
```

here is my approach to decode data from string,

```js
  getData() async {
  
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    
    String? resultData = prefs.getString('results');
    
    List<dynamic> decodedJson = jsonDecode(resultData!);
    
    print(decodedJson);
 
  }
```

resultData string,

[image]

resultData string after decode,

[image]

I am new to flutter and what I want is the proper way to decode this data from models. Below are my model classes.

```js
import 'dart:convert';

class Result {
  Result({
    required this.table,
    required this.data,
  });

  String table;
  List<Data> data;

  factory Result.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Result(
        table: json["table"],
        data: List<Data>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Data.fromJson(x))),
      );

  static String encode(List<dynamic> results) => json.encode(
        results.map((result) => result.toString()).toList(),
      );
}

class Data {
  Data({
    required this.subjectName,
    required this.year,
    required this.credits,
    required this.sOrder,
    required this.result,
    required this.onlineAssignmentResult,
  });

  String subjectName;
  String year;
  String credits;
  String sOrder;
  String result;
  String onlineAssignmentResult;

  factory Data.fromJson(json) => Data(
        subjectName: json["subject_name"],
        year: json["year"],
        credits: json["credits"],
        sOrder: json["s_order"],
        result: json["result"],
        onlineAssignmentResult: json["online_assignment_result"],
      );
}
```

Appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is in the wrong syntax for Flutter to decode with jsonDecode()

All strings and variable names need to be enclosed in " or '

I.e. {subject_name: should be {"subject_name":